# sitemap shortcoming

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I am constrained to using a SiteMap for authentication. I am an experienced developer that has not had to use the SiteMap previously, so I am probably missing something due to the paradigm shift.

in order to get around the url limitation in SiteMap, I <doh!>*cleverly*</doh!> appended a querystring value:

<siteMapNode url="workflow.aspx?Location=Process1" description="Process1">

<siteMapNode url="workflow.aspx?Location=Process2" description="Process2">

the page dynamically returns the appropriate information/display based on the querystring value, and I don't have multiple stub pages. everything worked and it seemed like a good idea, until...

managers now want to access the page and edit their employee's work aliased as them, so they need to click a link like this:

href=workflow.aspx?Location=Process1&UserID=12&IDWorkflowLocation=3340

{update to explanation}
it arrives at the page correctly, but

SiteMap.CurrentNode==null;

because there is already a querystring in the sitemap it doesn't append correctly.  I reaally don't want to have to make uniquely named stub .aspx pages.  any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
href=workflow.aspx?Location=Process1&amp;UserID=12&amp;IDWorkflowLocation=3340
```

Comment: nope.  it reaches the destination page, but then the SiteMap.CurrentNode ==null

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried programmatically modifying the site map nodes at runtime? This article explains how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178425.aspx

I have used this in the past, but I seem to remember that the **SiteMapResolve** event fires on every request (even if you define it on a specific WebForm).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, i took a look at this, but because the Sitemap.CurrentNode property is null when it arrives at the page this doesn't work.

Comment: apparently the problem is that because SiteMap already contains a querystring it is unable to process further querystring parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the SiteMap class, override the CurrentNode property and get some of your own logic in there to catch this.

Comment: Agreed. Override CurrentNode in the provider and return the node matched by the Http request.